# jq: how to get array of arrays with json object values from an array of objects

Tags: arrays, json, jq

having input json like so

```
[
  {
    "k1": "o1k1",
    "k2": "o1k2",
    "k_opt1": "o1k_xxx"
  },
  {
    "k1": "o2k1",
    "k2": "o2k2",
    "k_opt2": "o2k_yyy"
  }
]
```

i would like to get array of arrays with object values, so:

```
[
  [
    "o1k1",
    "o1k2",
    "o1k_xxx"
  ],
  [
    "o2k1",
    "o2k2",
    "o2k_yyy"
  ]
]
```

tried `.[] | to_entries[].value`, but it eats up the individual arrays - and produces just:

```
  "o1k1",
  "o1k2",
  "o1k_xxx",
  "o2k1",
  "o2k2",
  "o2k_yyy"
```

https://jqplay.org/s/riVFB79OCQS. Any advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-nest `map(…)` or `[.[]]` (or even `.[] |= …` on the array, not the object). All of these do what you want:

```bash
jq 'map(map(.))'     # nesting map(…) and map(…)
jq 'map([.[]])'      # nesting map(…) and [.[]]
jq '[.[] | [.[]]]'   # nesting [.[]] and [.[]]
jq '[.[] | map(.)]'  # nesting [.[]] and map(…)

jq '.[] |= map(.)'   # nesting .[] |= … and map(…)
jq '.[] |= [.[]]'    # nesting .[] |= … and [.[]]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/IxeXYf0_Z68)

Comment: blown my mind. qith your example it turned out i was quite close - `.[] | [to_entries[].value]` doest the trick. but your approach seems simpler - so i'm glad to use it. actually `.[] | [.[]]'` also did the job - no need for `=`. What I actually wanted to do is to "stringify" such array to later put it in `error` message. the original `error(.[] | [.[]]  | @tsv)` just printed the first line, so i ended up with `error( [.[] | [.[]]  | @tsv ] | join("\n") )` https://jqplay.org/s/riVFB79OCQS

Comment: @murison `.[] | [.[]]` first iterates over the array (decomposing it), and converts each item (initially being an object) to an array. However, with `|` instead of `|=`, the (outer) array remains decomposed, so you end up having a stream of two (previously inner) arrays, which may perfectly work out for your use-case, but is not an "array of arrays" anymore (as asked in the question).

Comment: you are of course right. thanks once again!

Answer (score -2):

Just loop through the array and replace objects with `Object.value()` which creates an array with values of the object.

**EDIT**: My bad somehow I got this question and thought it's about JS. I will still leave this though, might help someone x)

```js
const data = [
  {
    "k1": "o1k1",
    "k2": "o1k2",
    "k_opt1": "o1k_xxx"
  },
  {
    "k1": "o2k1",
    "k2": "o2k2",
    "k_opt2": "o2k_yyy"
  }
]


function getKeys(arr) {
  arr.forEach((dataset, i) => {
    arr[i] = Object.values(dataset)
  })
  return arr
}

console.log(getKeys(data))
```